# Any suggestions on filling gaps in wood flooring? - Pine Tongue Groove

Tags: wood, pine

Any suggestions on filling gaps in wood flooring?
Pine tongue groove was used that is usually used for wall or ceiling.
Have no idea why they put this on the floor?
I was thinking cutting wood strips and gluing them in then sand.
Better idea may be to rip it up and put a real floor down.
Impossible to clean for the owner.

[image: Floor]

Comment: I don't think there's any reasonable way you can fill these. There are ways you can fill them but the amount of effort required would be immense, not to mention the amount of filler required! And I don't think you could guarantee the filler would be durable enough with foot traffic and wood movement. Wood strips seem like a viable alternative until you factor in making them to the correct profile in the first place (a not-inconsiderable task) and then cleaning every groove thoroughly beforehand so that they'll glue in properly. Just don't think the amount of work required is justified.

Comment: Personally I would do one of 3 things, 1, live with the floor as-is and just accept that the grooves may get dirty 2, use carpeting or lots of rugs 3, replace the entire floor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fill these gaps in.  Any wood floor needs to expand and contract across its width and the tongue and groove profile of the individual strips allow the floor to absorb changes in width without buckling. All wood floors will have a similar approach for the same reason.  I will grant you that pine makes for a floor that is very susceptible to scratches and dents, and the exposed screw is singularly unattractive!  If you want invisible seams consider a plastic laminate flooring in a wood pattern.